# Are DocumentDB stored procedures safe for simultaneous executions by multiple clients?

Tags: multithreading, stored-procedures, transactions, locking, azure-cosmosdb

How can I ensure each execution of a stored procedure can complete it's entire transaction without the document state being modified by another simultaneous execution of the same procedure by another client?

Is there anything I need to do to ensure a lock on the documents that are being modified?
Is there a way to implement something like a T-SQL `TRANSACTION` to ensure that the entire operation is rolled back if an error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures are executed on a database snapshot in isolation. Either everything in the operation works or it's all rolled back.

You should still use the etag option for any `replaceDocument()` or `deleteDocument()` calls to ensure that a document hasn't been changed out under you.

```
etag = oldDocument._etag;
options = {etag: etag};
stillQueueing = collection.replaceDocument(documentLink, newDocument, options);
```